# How do I produce this datetime format in PHP? xsd time formatting in PHP

Tags: php, datetime, xsd, saml

I am performing an SSO using SAML. My XML is being created in a PHP script and I need to format the date time for what is called issueInstance in SAML

I need this format:

> 2015-05-04T01:12:04.582Z

I tried `date('c')` but it gives a format like:

> 2015-07-17T18:32:55+00:00

The response is throwing an incorrect time format error:

```
IssueInstant is invalid (wrapped: Unparseable date: "2015-07-17T18:32:55+00:00")
```

I am not sure what the .582Z is on the tail end of the datetime so I can not figure out how to format it and google has not been any help looking for xsd time formatting in PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.582 == 582 milliseconds` and `Z == Zulu == +00:00`. That's a valid ISO8601 timestamp, so I think you're just dealing with a poorly-written parser that's implemented one specific format.

PHP's ISO8601 format does not include milliseconds:

```
var_dump(DateTime::ISO8601); // string(13) "Y-m-d\TH:i:sO"
```

and there's no flag for ms, but you can fake it:

```
var_dump(date("Y-m-d\TH:i:s.000O")); // string(28) "2015-07-17T11:56:00.000-0700"
```

or you can kludge in milliseconds if you *really* want with:

```
var_dump(date(sprintf("Y-m-d\TH:i:s.%sO", substr(microtime(),2,3))));
// string(28) "2015-07-17T12:05:51.044-0700"
```